# Emacs freezing for a few seconds while in use

Tags: usb, emacs

My EMACS tends to freeze for a few seconds while I am typing code, and I am not sure what is wrong as when I monitor my CPU and RAM usage, there are no visible spikes.

System Info:

```
Ubuntu 14.0.4
Emacs 24.3
1.8 GHz i5
8 GB RAM
```

Emacs Configurations:

```
Running Python 3.4
rope
elpy
yasnippet
jedi
```

The OS is currently running on my thumb drive which I stick into my laptop, and I am wondering if that is the issue. It is a USB 3.0 drive, in a USB 3.0 compatible port. I have yet to test the speeds on that port yet (partly because I don't know how to yet). But thought that I might ask first before I go on and make mistakes

Update: Went to benchmark my USB and I found out that there were sudden dips in the read and write speeds. So I went on to clone everything onto a faster USB (San Disk Extreme 64GB) and so far the freezes seem to have stopped.